# remove image by pressing delete in browser

Tags: php, jquery, web-services, browser, cross-browser

how can i detect that delete key is pressed 
i am working with lot of images generated dynamically with php. now i want to provide a functionality so that when delete key is pressed that images is removed from page but the problem is that how can i detect that a delete key is pressed 
please point me in the right direction such as

```
$('img').delete(function(){

    // delete code
});
```

is this possible using jquery, javascript or php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this: https://api.jquery.com/keydown/
Inside the function you can remove the image.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [onkeydown](https://api.jquery.com/keydown/) to detect a key press and then check if it is the delete key.

You can check for key codes [here](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)